# Solving symbolically. Choosing the symbols in the final representation

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

Consider the following simple three expressions:

```
from sympy import *

x1,y1,x2,y2,x,y,a,xn,yn = symbols('x1 y1 x2 y2 x y a xn yn')

yn = (1 - xn)/(1 - a*xn)
xn = (x - x1)/(x2 - x1)          
yn = (y - y1)/(y2 - y1)
```

I would like to express `y` as a function of `x`, `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` and `a`.

How do I do that? Can `sub` be used to do this type of expansion / simplification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your equations represent *equality*, and not variable assignmnent, then your system of equations is:

xn = (x - x1)(x2 - x1)

(1 - xn)/(1 - a*xn) = (y - y1)/(y2 - y1)

This can be solved in SymPy as follows:

```
from sympy import *
x1, y1, x2, y2, x, y, a = symbols('x1 y1 x2 y2 x y a')
xn  = (x - x1)/(x2 - x1)   
yn1 = (1 - xn)/(1 - a*xn)       
yn2 = (y - y1)/(y2 - y1)
eq0 = yn1 - yn2

solve(eq0, y)
```

which returns:

```
[(a*x*y1 - a*x1*y1 - x*y1 + x*y2 + x1*y1 - x2*y2)/(a*x - a*x1 + x1 - x2)]
```

A bit of explanation:

- `xn` didn't depend on `yn`, so we can just define it as an expression, rather than create a symbol for it on it's own.
- The expression `eq0` is the `yn` equivalence equations from above, rearranged to have only `0` on the right hand side. Many numerical solvers have the same interface, and sympy borrows it here.
- `solve` takes an expression equivalent to 0 and symbols to solve for. Here we only want to solve for `y`.
- The results from `solve` are an iterable of solutions (a `list`). Since SymPy only found one solution, the list is only 1 long. Other equations might return more.